# How to save extra csv row of data in to an array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have a csv upload functionality that saves in to my database table. I would like to modify this to read an extra row of data and format the array accordingly.

The table will look like this:

| Date | Cost Type 1 | Cost Type 2 | Cost Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | £50.00 | £10.00 | £90.00 |
| 01/01/21 | 1 | 3 | 10 |
| 02/01/21 | 5 | 4 | 12 |

I am saving the cost heading against each figure. So before I get to saving the actual data, I want to read a cost price for each type and save it in to my array as well.

```
$formattedArray = [];
foreach($the_array as $element) {
  $formattedArray[] = [
    "cost" => array_keys($element)[0],
    "demand" => array_values($element)[0],
  ];
}
```

The final array should look like this:

```
array(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 01/01/21
        [cost] => Cost Type 1
        [demand] => 1
        [total] => £50.00
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 01/01/21
        [cost] => Cost Type 2
        [demand] => 3
        [total] => £10.00
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 01/01/21
        [cost] => Cost Type 3
        [demand] => 10
        [total] => £90.00
    )
 )
```

My csv upload function looks like this:

```
  if ($this->request->data['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
    $i = 1;
    if (($file = fopen($this->request->data['file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
      while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {
        if ($i == 1){
          $header = $row;
        }else{
          if (count($header) == count($row)){
            $uploads[] = array_combine($header, $row);
          }else{
            $error_rows[] = $row;
          }
        }
        $i++;
      }
      fclose($file);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This question needs proper detail information first of all. That “table” you have shown - is that supposed to be what your actual CSV file contains? Then what is the logic behind creating your “final array”? That appears to have taken the values from the first data row only – what about the second one? If that does not matter, then explain why not.

Comment: My csv currently contains the above, with no costs - I want to add in the costs. All rows matter, I've only shown the first loop in the array as an example. The headings will vary with each spreadsheet, so I am encoding the data when saving it - I need to save the cost type and price alongside every demand frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got your question, You mean to say that the data doesn't start from the 2nd row, instead the 2nd row contains an additional piece of info and then the data starts from 3rd row.

In that case all you need to do is parse the 2nd row just as you are parsing the 1st row, and then store and use the value in/from variables.

```
if ($this->request->data['file']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $i          = 1;
    $finalArray = [];

    if (($file = fopen($this->request->data['file']['tmp_name'], "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ',', '"')) !== FALSE) {
            if ($i == 1) {
                $header = $row;
            } elseif ($i == 2) {
                $priceInfo = $row;
            } else {
                if (count($header) == count($row)) {
                    $rowArray = [];
                    for ($i = 1; $i < count($row); $i++) { // Starting from 1 as we need to skip the first column
                        $rowArray[] = [
                            "cost"   => $header[$i],
                            "demand" => $row[$i],
                            "total"  => $priceInfo[$i],
                            "date"  => $row[0],

                        ];
                    }
                    $finalArray[] = $rowArray;
                } else {
                    $error_rows[] = $row;
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean thank you. This answer is very close to what I need - how would I also save the date value of each row inside this array?

Comment: Where do you want the date value? Can you update the question with a sample of the output array?

Comment: The date would just sit inside the array with the costs - I have updated my sample array above

Comment: Then you can always access the date from the first element of the `$row` array. Updated answer.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your help this is now working for me